# How to get the fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath() from within pickerView: titleForRow

Tags: swift, uipickerview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UIPickerView and it's datasource is a fetchedResultsController.

My delegate func:

```
   func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String
{
    let task: Task = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(row) as Task
    return task.name
}
```

results in this error:

```
'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'NSIndexPath'
```

I tried to cast row as NSIndexPath before passing it, that resulted in the same error:

```
 'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'NSIndexPath'
```

I'm guessing that fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath() tries to cast the parameter it receives?

What might I be doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` uses index paths (having a *row* and a *section* component)
so that it can be used as a data source for table views with multiple sections.

In your case, you can create an `NSIndexPath` from the row number with

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: 0)
let task = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as Task
```

Comment: I just wanted to post the exact same answer but then I saw in the documentation: indexPath:forRow:inSection (not available in Swift) ?

Comment: @zisoft: That must be a documentation problem. I compiled the code in Xcode 6.0.1 before posting the answer. Will check Xcode 6.1 ...

Comment: That sounds good. I'm currently downloading the Xcode 6.1 update so I couldn't try :-)

Comment: Thanks guys! Is there a reason that fetchedResultsController is mostly used with tables? I mean should I be taking those results and making an array for use with a UIPicker?

Comment: @zisoft: It compiles in Xcode 6.1 GM Seed 2 as well. I don't think that it changed in the final 6.1 release.

Comment: @SamLuther: "mainly used" was perhaps a bad wording and I have changed it. But a fetched results controller needs the flexibility to be used with a table view having multiple sections and therefore uses an index path instead of a single row number for addressing. – Using the fetched results controller as data source for a picker view is fine, just set the section number to zero where needed.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the clarification and your answer, appreciate it.

Comment: @MartinR: Xcode 6.1 just updated the documentation. It is fixed now.